# How to make a reflection catcher, when you can see reflections through other reflections?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, reflection

I have been able to set up a basic reflection catcher, using a separate render pass and the GlossyIndirect setting. However, when making the corner in the back, and the reflections in the floor as shown in the picture, the reflection catching surfaces themselves become visible. How do I stop this?

Edit: I have found a solution involving turning off glossy rays for the surface, however this also gets rid of the "secondary" reflections of the main Dalek object (like the reflection in the floor, seen in the right-most reflection)

[image]